# External powershell scripts only run once when action called

Tags: powershell

I am trying to call an outside ps script to run every time files are created. The monitoring and logging of files work well, but the Invoke-Expression of running the external script only runs one time even if more files are created. How do I run the external script with every time a new file is created.

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "c:\mypath"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.txt*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath                
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "C:\mypath\log.txt" -value $logline
                Invoke-Expression (start powershell ("C:\MyOtherScript.ps1")) ###### This only runs one time even if file is changes and logged
              }

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED

    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

EDIT: This got it working incase anyone find themselves here looking to solve the porblem

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "c:\mypath"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.txt*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath                
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "C:\mypath\log.txt" -value $logline
                Start-Process powershell -argument "C:\MyOtherScript.ps1"
              }

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED

    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    #while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of your loop at the end?  Also, why are you using `Invoke-Expression` instead of just `Start-Process`

Comment: The loop  at the end was in to original code to monitor files her https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created

Comment: In searching for how to do this I found 'Invoke-expression' or 'invoke-item' were the methods of running other scripts. I am new to powershell.

Comment: I was able to get it working with using `Start-Process powershell -argument "C:\MyOtherScript.ps1"` and commenting out the `while ($true) {sleep 5}`

Comment: Great, I'll contribute that as the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invoke-Expression` is not recommend over using `&` due to security concerns.  In your example, however, I'd suggest `Start-Process`:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'powershell' -ArgumentList @('-File','"C:\MyOtherScript.ps1"')
```